# Can we change Standard lookup search column

Tags: lookup

In standard lookup, name column of the related objects becomes the search criteria. Is it possible to change the name column to some other column for search in standard?

Answer (score 7):

You should use Enhanced lookups that are supported for accounts, contacts, users, opportunities, and custom objects.

For enabling Enhanced Lookups:

- From Setup, enter *Search Settings* in the *Quick Find box*, then select
  *Search Settings*.
- In the Lookup Settings area, select the objects for which you want to enable enhanced lookup functionality. Currently, only account, contact, user, and custom object lookups can use this feature.
- Click **Save**.

If you have enabled it then you will see two radio buttons in lookup window:

- Name
- All Fields

You cannot search based on specific fields. Either you can search based on Name or All fields

Comment: I have enabled it and i am using that field in vf page...But i am got getting all the colmuns..Do Enhanced lookups work in vf page

Comment: Suppose you have lookup of Account. Then go to Setup > Customize > Accounts > Search Layout > Edit Lookup Dialogs. Select Fields which you want to see in Lookup Search result table.

Comment: That is for seeing.. I need for searching...And i am using that field in vf page..

Comment: By enabling Enhanced Lookup you can search records based on all fields values

Comment: I have enabled the enhanced lookup .. I am using that field in vf page.. I am not getting those option to search all fields..

Comment: It will work on vf page. It might be a case that you are using Enhanced lookup for child instead of parent object. Suppose you are using Contact's fields on vf page and you want to select Account using enhanced lookup then enable Enhanced lookup for Account in Search settings.

Comment: I have 2 objects RFP__c & RFP_Child__c.. There is a lookup field in RFP_Child__c to RFP__c .. So i have enabled Enhanced lookup for RFP__c .. Still it is not coming..

Comment: If you have enabled it then you will see two radio buttons in lookup window:   Search ->  1. Name  2. All Fields
You cannot search based on specific fields. Either you can search based on Name or All fields